onOpen trigger fail when I define a constant within the function it uses - what am I doing wrong?
My onOpen trigger works fine - until I add a line to define a constant in a function it uses.
The line I have commented out defines a constant I've called voucher. My intention is for the if statement to check if the date is valid (this part works fine) OR if the value of voucher exists within the voucherCode array.
When I add a line to define constant I've called voucher then the function does not run. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function onOpen() {
  licTestDisplay();
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Quiz Controls')
    .addItem('✔️Check answer & Update diagram', 'question')
    .addToUi();
  // }
}
function licTestDisplay() {
  // Why does the line below prevent the function from working when it is not commented out ?
  //const voucher = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById(licence).asTable().getCell(0, 2).getText().asString().trim().valueOf();
  if ((now < date1) || (voucherArray.indexOf(voucher) > -1)) {
    var remainingTime = Math.floor((date1 - now) / 86400000) - 1
    const message = `Days remaining: ${remainingTime}`;
    SlidesApp.getUi().alert("Evaluation licence", `${message}`, SlidesApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  } else {
    const message2 = `Please visit https://xxxxxxx.com to purchase`;
    SlidesApp.getUi().alert("Sorry - your evaluation licence has lapsed", `${message2}`, SlidesApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

const date1 = new Date('June 23, 2024 00:00:00 -0500');
const now = new Date();
const licence = 'g2e2bb4ab0a1_0_0'
// Adding the constant with global scope also causes the same problem
//const voucher = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById(licence).asTable().getCell(0, 2).getText().asString().trim().valueOf();

Here is a link to the file

Because a script has an onOpen function, the project global variable assignation is done using limited authorization. Considering this, avoid calling methods in the global scope and by the onOpen function that requires authorization to be executed when having an onOpen function or using an installable trigger instead of a simple one.
Note: The event object includes a property with the authorization mode: .authMode.
The following example was taken from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle showing the use of this method.
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp.
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    if (workflowStarted) {
      menu.addItem('Check workflow status', 'checkWorkflow');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

While the above example uses SpreadsheetApp, the authMode property is present on the event object, for all supported editors Docs, Forms, Sheets and Slides.

Thanks for responding. I'll try to work my way through to an understanding of all you've said. I guess I'll just have to add that voucher code check to each of the appropriate functions potentially used after document has opened - unless you've got a better idea on how to allow reference during onOpen to a value held within the document. - I don't think I can store the value using the Properties service as I need it to stay in place when the file is copied.
